# Array Formula in vba code with coping the formula down

Tags: vba, excel

I work on the code that will calculate Array Formula basing on how many records is in the column N:N that is 11 columns earlier (offset 11). I want to use the formula with array that will use the parallel row from the column N:N and copy down until the last record in column N:N exist. However, for now, formula copies down basing on the first record only instead of taking the row in parallel:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

TargetRow = 4 

   .Range("N4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 11).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(Name&INDEX(Names_Area,MATCH(RC[-11],Name&Name_Origin,0),2),"""")"

    End With
```

I heard about fill down function or something alike but I am not sure how to insert it here. 
How can I fix it so when the formula copies down into rows it takes the row in parallel and not all the time N4 (that is the first row of records).
I will appreciate any help.

I also want to mention that any other formula without array works and copies formula down basing on the rows in column N:N that are in paralell.

Comment: .AutoFill should work for the range

Answer (score 1):

Try with .Autofill. something like:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    TargetRow = 4 

    .Range("N4").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(Name&INDEX(Names_Area,MATCH(RC[-11],Name&Name_Origin,0),2),"""")"
    .Range("N4").AutoFill .Range("N4:N12")

End With
```

I have used an example end point of N12 for the autofill which you can adjust.

Though note you are actually going to column Y with:

```
.Range("N4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 11)
```

So you may want to ensure you autofill and populate formula in the actual column you want to fill.

Maybe something like:

```
.Range("N4").Offset(0, 11).FormulaArray =
```

Reference:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/500971-how-copy-array-formula-down-vba-macro.html

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have tried your idea using:                                         .Range("N4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 11).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(RU_Project.ID&INDEX(RU_WBS_Area,MATCH(RC[-11],RU_Project.ID&RU_WBS_Origin,0),2),"""")"
  .Range("N4").AutoFill .Range("N4:N12"     But the formula result in next rows still bases the result on the first N4, not according to row in parallel in Column N:N

Comment: you have to apply to one column I think rather than N to Y (?). Otherwise you would need the formula in the first row of all the relevant columns before doing the fill down. It fills down not across and down.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("N4", .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 11)
        .Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(Name&INDEX(Names_Area,MATCH(RC[-11],Name&Name_Origin,0),2),"""")"
        .Formula = .Cells(1, 1).Formula
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code but maybe I misunderstood because I didn't get the result right. By the part: '.Cells(1,1)' are you giving just an example where the result will be placed? So If my result should start in column Y, target row 4, Should the part of the code be: '.Cells(4,26)' ? or how?

Comment: Nope. `.Cells(1,1) is pointing at the first cell in the _referenced_ range in the `With` statement. So, in this case it's pointing to cell "N4" of "Sheet1" sheet

Comment: @Dozens, please check my code against your _original_ question data, and if it works as per this site rules you may consider marking answer as accepted. Otherwise you can come back and detail what didn't work. While if you have to change your _original_ question data, then you may post a _new_ question along with your efforts

Comment: Ok, I will do that